# Is river navigation in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have been looking for references to support a 3000+ mile river journey.  There are several references available, but I have not found a single home for them.  This journey is in the US and even the federal sites are broken up on several different sites (*some which work better than others, many with dead links between them*).  Additionally there are several local web sites that have information about rivers within a 20 or 30 mile stretch.

I am considering trying to compile an overview here on The Great Outdoors.  I am still working through the how in my head, but probably something like.

"What are the navigation considerations on the Ohio between Pittsburgh PA.& Wheeling WV?"

With a detailed answer that includes public launches, river side (or near) services, lodging/camping and lists all the relevant web references.

Tags would probably be 'River_Navigation' & 'Ohio-River'

Currently I am thinking 100-150 miles of river per Q&A, with links in the question to the next Q&A up or down the river and for any forks with a Q&A.  Currently in my plan I would research the answer, then post the question and answer at the same time.

Is "The Great Outdoors" a place for this? Any other thoughts?

Comment: I posted the first quesition [What are the navigation considerations on the Ohio River between Pittsburgh PA.& Wheeling WV?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/) - I have not even begun to develop the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first:

- It's perfectly valid to [self answer your own
  question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)
- You need to be [careful not to self-promote too
  much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)
- and not to produce duplicate Q&A's.

Providing each answer and question fit's within these (and all the general [SE guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)). I can't see any reason why you can't do this.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Liam - I think the adventure sounds awesome, and is likely to not just touch on river navigation but a whole host of associated topics.

In addition to your idea of posting question and answer, you can also post questions as you come to them and let the community here help with your research.